# Export Datas from react-native app to csv

Tags: android, ios, csv, react-native, cross-platform

I've been trying to export datas from react-native app to a csv file for a few days but unsuccessfully.

I need to create a cross-plateform app that cat get some data from user even without any network.
When the tablet is connected to internet, I have to sync it with my server.

My question is how to save my data even when I close the app or reboot the tablet.

Please excuse my English ;)
Thanks

Comment: You can use AsyncStorage  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage Or SQLite storage https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage , or react-native-mongodb https://github.com/antoniopresto/react-native-local-mongodb